# Represent 16 bit signed int as a value between 0-100

Tags: c, math

I am relatively new to programming and have always been terrible with math. I have a program that takes a 16 bit signed `INT` `-32,768 +32,768` I would like to represent these values as `1-100` on the positive side and `-1 - -100` on the negative side so that they are easier to work with. So basically 100 would be equal to 32,768; 50 would be equal to 16,384; etc. How can I accomplish this easily? I am programming in C although I think this is more of a math question than anything.

Comment: You know that some information will be lost, right?

Comment: it does not have to be perfect

Comment: It really depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve with your mapping since there is no injective mapping from Z_p -> Z_q where q > p.

Comment: what are you trying to achive?  you can simply scale things by 327, but seems a bit odd

Comment: I am only trying to achieve a speed so if the joystick is position all the way to the right it will read 32,768 so 100% speed of the servo.

Comment: So you are attempting to map a percentage? I believe someone has explained this below (divide by max value, multiply by 100 for percent - take absolute value if necessary).

Comment: You can't fit -32768 ... 32768 in 16 bits. "I am relatively new to programming and have always been terrible with math." -- That's going to be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements seem strange, because if you're trying to make integers than you can just use the range [-100, 100] in the 16-bit integer value (usually a `short`) and... well, leave it that way.

If you're also looking for it to contain *decimal* values, then you need to consider that it will not be able to represent the range from [-100, 100] in a very nice manner... If you're asking to store a 16-bit integer value from another 16-bit integer value, you can do that It'll just be extremely messy:

```
int16_t normalized = ( rawvalue / 327 ); // <--- scaled, rawvalue is int16_t
```

You're losing precision and there's aliasing on certain ranges of values, though, so this doesn't seem... great. If you can store a `float` or a `double`, either or can hold the values [-100, 100] a little bit more nicely:

```
double normalized = ( rawvalue * ( 32768.0 / 100.0 ) );
// float normalized = /*... */ Append "f" for "float" math instead on those constants
```

Your requirements seem... weird, but that's how you would do it. Good luck!

EDIT:

As a final recommendation, I would say that unless another piece of your program DEMANDS 100 -> -100, if you're using `float` or `double` using the range [-1.0, 1.0] is **infinitely** nicer to work with and can be a lot more powerful when doing things like scaling numbers and such that go into other inputs and outputs, including raw integer values that will go into a server. (INT16)(0.75 * MAX_MOTOR_VALUE) is way better than finagling with 100 to -100.

Comment: In modern C, the integer division maps [-326, 326] all to 0. This is twice as many numbers than map to -1 or 1.

Comment: Yep, which is why it's not a good idea to do the vision as an int16 and better to do it with floating-point numbers or to use a special `round` function (which might employ floating point numbers anyways).

Comment: That's.. ... exactly what I did above. You're just added an extra condition check for no reason. What...?

Comment: @Anonymous Seriously, that doesn't change anything: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=dc73446aa6d2164ae9bb491f08164495-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba

Comment: You're right, I got the code wrong. You need to add (using int to avoid overflow) `sgn(x) * 327/2` to x before doing the division.

Comment: Orrr... you can just use `float` and `double` and save yourself the agony altogether! :D

Comment: The answer is simply wrong, for the results will be spread between -99..99, and 100 will be reached for -32768 only.

Comment: @Gangnus It's not wrong, because that's how integer division works. If you need more precision for intermediate numbers, you either use float/double or you use a larger type (int) and do some spill-over addition and division. The OP wasn't specific in what he wanted, so in the end I answered him both ways. Also, he wouldn't have accepted the answer if it didn't suit his needs. :D

Comment: If you want to reach some target, you should not search for escuses, but for a solution. And the solution is very easy: you should multiply by 101, not 100. And in order not to get 101 in the case of -32768, divide by -32769. That's all.

Comment: Or just use a float/double and be done with it, seeing as that's what these data types are good for unless you need to deal in ultra-precise fixed-precision mathematics. .... Which he _doesn't_, AFAICT.

Answer (score 1):

16-bit integers can have only 2<sup>16</sup>=65536 distinct values at most, from -32767 to +32767 (in non-2's-complement representation) or from from -32768 to +32767 (in 2's-complement representation). So, really you want 32767 to be equal to 100 and -32767 equal to -100.

Here's what you could do:

```
int int2fixed(int x)
{
  return x * 32767LL / 100;
}

int fixed2int(int x)
{
  return x * 100LL / 32767;
}
```

Comment: In modern C, this maps twice as many values to 0 than to 1 or -1.

Comment: @Anonymous Elaborate please?

Comment: @Gangnus You didn't read either my answer or the C standard. Please read either.

Comment: look at your first line :  -32767 to +32767 is there. Sorry, I am just keeping to Ansi C.

Comment: And even so your answer is very bad, for you'll never have the 100 value.

Comment: @Gangnus FYI, ANSI C defines the minimum range for `short` and `int` from -32767 to +32767, not from -32768 to +32767. And I will always have 100 because 100 * 32767LL / 100 = 32767LL and then 32767 * 100LL / 32767 = 100LL.

Answer (score 0):

Divide it by the maximum value, multiply by 100, and truncate to an integer. For example (combining the maximum value division and multiplication by 100 into 1 step):

```
int normalize(int a)
{
    assert(a >= -32768 && a <= 32767)
    return (int)ceil(a / 327.68);
}
```

Comment: If ints are 16 bits then 32768 will overflow.

Answer (score 0):

All answers her are forgetting, that we need to MOSTLY EVENLY spread the results among 1..100. And these answers never reach the 100.

```
int normalize(int a)
{

    return (int)(a*101L/ 32769);
}
```